# Is mixing the old and new C++ function syntax in a class allowed?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

This code actually works:

```
class Abstract {
    virtual auto foo() -> int = 0;
};

class Concrete: public Abstract {
    int foo() { cout << "blah!" << endl; return 1; }
} instance;
```

I understand that the function gets mangled and linked to be the same function signature, but is this kind of mixing actually legal in C++14?

Comment: I'm assuming `Concrete` should be deriving from `Abstract` there? (P.S: If you want to make sure that it is in fact overriding the base function, use the override keyword. If it fails to compile then you know they don't match.)

Comment: Since c++ is backwards compatible it shouldn't be a problem, if it's wanted is another question ( style guide )

Comment: @deW1 *generally* / *mostly* backwards compatible would be more accurate ;-)

Comment: @Borgleader obviously. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto foo()->int` and `int foo()` are the same prototype expressed with different syntax, so the second function is an override of the first, and will replace it in runtime dispatch (being virtual) as usually.

The *right-side return* syntax, has normally another purpose, like

```
template<class A, class B>
auto some_combination(A a, B b) -> decltype(a+b);
```

otherwise requiring a more complex syntax like

```
temlate<class A, class B>
decltype(std::declval<A>()+std::declval<B>()) some_combination(A a,B b);
```

since `a` and `b` are not defined  in the left side of the prototype.

When the return type is trivially defined, left or right placement is essentially irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's legal because actually you are fully defining your function.
As a minimal, working example (note the `override`):

```
class Abstract {
    virtual auto foo() -> int = 0;
};

class Concrete: public Abstract {
    int foo() override { return 1; }
} instance;

int main() { }
```

Here the return type isn't deduced, it's explicitly declared by means of a trailing return type.
It's equivalent to:

```
class Abstract {
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};
```

It would have been different if you were using this:

```
class Abstract {
    virtual auto foo() = 0;
};
```

Here template deduction is involved and *virtual functions cannot have deduced return type* (that is more or less the error string from GCC).

Comment: Why would I need to use override when the original function is pure virtual?

Comment: @Philipp Override says explicitly to the reader what's the intention of the developer. Moreover, it will results in a compilation error if there isn't such a virtual function in the base class. Why not?